# how to point to the next memory in a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, hashtable

these are my structure declarations

```
struct Package_Node
{
    int bar_code;
    float package_weight;
    struct Package_Node *next;//_packaged;
};

struct Key_Node
{
    int key;
    struct Package_Node *next;//_package;
};
```

and this is how have added some random items in them

```
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            barcodeTemp = rand() % max_value + 1;
            keyTemp = barcodeTemp % X;
            tempWeight = rand() % 500 + 1;
            totalPackages[i].bar_code=barcodeTemp;
            totalPackages[i].package_weight=tempWeight;

        }
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            cout << totalPackages[i].bar_code <<endl;
            cout << totalPackages[i].package_weight << endl;
        }
```

I am wondering that do I need to add something inside the code, and outside of the structure to create a linked list?? To be more clear, I am creating (lets say) 5 random packages using the Package_node structure which have random values of bar_code and package_weight. I am using hash-table methods to determine where in key_node will the package information be stored. if key_node[1] has two elements and I want to add a third one, what do I do to add the third element at the end without removing anything.It has to be a link list and the end must always point to NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like this to your for loop:

```
totalPackages[i].next = NULL;
if (i>0) {
  totalPackages[i-1].next = &totalPackages[i];
}
```

Comment: what is the significance of the "if" statement and why is it totalPackages[i-1].next instead of just totalPackages[i]

Comment: I assumed that totalPackages is an array or std::vector of fixed size and the if statement prevents you from trying to acces an element in the vector at index -1.

Comment: As you want to let the previous element in the list point to the next one, you should set the pointer in the previous element to the current element.

Comment: BTW, consider using a std::list or std::forward_list (C11), so you do not have to implement these kind of stuff yourself.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have mentioned it, totalPackages is a dynamic array, does that make any difference?

Comment: it has to be from the standard library. Its for a school project.

Comment: No not really, I actually tried to say the array has a certain size before the for loop starts and does not change size, while adding elements.